# Bug in Math.Abs

Tags: c#

I want to convert a very large negative number in C# to a positive value, but I know Math.Abs can fail when you hit `Decimal.MaxValue`. I know this number is very large, but there is a slight chance the the data coming over my network may have this value, or larger. I was wondering if there is away to just flip the sign bit of the number in C#.

Here is my code right now:

```
int bucket = Math.Abs(sdmpobject.SnapshotHandle.GetHashCode()) % numPartitions;
```

This uses `Math.Abs()`, I am just wondering if there is away to only flip the sign bit?

Comment: GetHasCode returns an int btw.

Comment: I guess what he means is the `MinValue` `-2,147,483,648` so its absolute won't be representable in int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetHashCode()` always returns a 32bit integer (`int`). There is no way this can exceed `Decimal.MaxValue`.
I assume that using `GetHashCode()` here is the actual error.

Comment: Yes, I know this, but if an error occurs I need the value to be correct no matter what, its just a precaution.

Comment: @user1765444: Precaution against what? And what error are you talking about?

Comment: If for some reason the value return is the largest negative the Math.Abs() fails, my program has a hard time handling this, I only test this in Nunit, this should not happen in thhe real world, just being careful.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I assume he needs check for `-2,147,483,648` which on `Abs` would overflow the int

Comment: I figured out a way to do this:                                     int bucket = (sdmpobject.SnapshotHandle.GetHashCode() & int.MaxValue) % numPartitions;

Comment: @user1765444: This doesn't "flip the negative sign".

Answer (score 2):

`GetHashCode()` will return an `int`, not a `Decimal`.

`Math.Abs(int)` will only fail when the `int` passed is equal to `int.MinValue`, so you can just test for that condition explicitly:

```
int myValue = sdmpobject.SnapshotHandle.GetHashCode();
int absValue = myValue == int.MinValue ? int.MaxValue : Math.Abs(myValue);
int bucket = absValue % numPartitions;
```

This assumes it is acceptable to you to be off by one for that rare condition. Since your result is in a variable called "bucket", maybe you want to correct for that off-by-one like this:

```
int myValue = sdmpobject.SnapshotHandle.GetHashCode();
int bucket;
if (myValue == int.MinValue)
{
    bucket = ((int.MaxValue % numPartitions) + 1) % numPartitions;
}
else
{
    int bucket = Math.Abs(myValue) % numPartitions;
}
```

The reason you can't just "flip the sign" for all values, is that signed data types can typically hold one more negative number than positive numbers, so they cannot represent the absolute value of the most negative number they can hold.

Comment: If you're looking for evenly distributed behavior, you should map `int.MinValue` to `0` rather than to `int.MaxValue`.  The constructor of `System.Random` makes this error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `Abs` which fails, it's the numeric range of the value which is exceeded.

Therefore you may need to take another numeric type to avoid a problem - what type/range is the original number from the network?

Answer (score 0):

In your question you mentioned `decimal` but the example you gave was with `int`.

Also:

> This uses Math.Abs(), I am just wondering if there is away to only flip the sign bit?

Yes, there is a way but you don't want to *just flip the* sign bit because that wouldn't give you the reciprocal value (I.e. flipping the sign bit on -1 would not result in 1)